# Mysql and PHP checking to see if name exists and last date of contact

Tags: php, mysql

I have several names and dates in my database, and I am looking for a way to only view an individual's name once and only show that name if their last date of contact was more than 6 months ago.

I know how to view an entry only once using:

```
$xyz= $db->query("SELECT * FROM dbname GROUP BY name");
```

and i also know how to view a date of less than 6 months using:

```
if (strtotime($xyz['date']) <= strtotime("-6 months")) {
    do stuff;
}
```

but I just can not figure out a way to combine them.

Comment: Actually, your SQL query will return every row in your table. You should use `LIMIT 1` to view one row.

Comment: @rybo111: Read it more closely. In those rows returned, only one per `name` will be provided. That's precisely what the OP said it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to SKY's orig. answer, you want the MAX (most recent) date to be < (older than) 6 mo.

You likely won't need to GROUP BY with this method as only one row should have the max date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbname a
WHERE dateCol < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
  AND dateCol = (SELECT MAX(dateCol)
                 FROM dbname b
                 WHERE b.name = a.name)
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks danielml01. The main problem I was having was to NOT show a person's name when they were in there multiple times with multiple dates. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbname 
where dateCol > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Should be `<`, not `>`.

Comment: This is close, but it shows me a person's name if any one of their dates are less than 6 months ago. I'd like it to NOT show me a person's name at all if any one of their dates are in that 6 month range.

Comment: @skewbert: I'm sure it's within your capability to invert the condition by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a581b/6

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbname
WHERE 
  {YOUR_DATETIME_FIELD}  <= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
GROUP BY 
  name
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show to you user names if their last date of contact was more than 6 months ago but NOT less than 6 months ago

```
SELECT name 
FROM dbname 
WHERE dateCol < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM dbname WHERE dateCol > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: _"more than 6 months ago but NOT less than 6 months ago"_ aka ... more than 6 months ago